# How is RecordReader initialize invoked in MapReduce API?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Could someone please shed some light on how the RecordReader initialize, progress and close method are invoked in MapReduce API. All I could find(w.r.t initialize) was 'initialize will be called once at initialization'.

I know that using the InputFormat we get the split and pass it to the createRecordReader to get the instance of RecordReader. In the mapper run method we'll be using the nextKeyValue, getCurrentKey and getCurrentValue.

Comment: I think you need to go over the code...

Comment: @almasshaikh: Thanks for the response. I did search for the information but I couldn't get any. Guess i'm missing something out when going through the framework control flow. I'll have a look at it again.

Comment: The quickest way to find is to get source codes, and in eclipse check references(ctrl+shift+g) for the target method. I wish I could provide some light, but soon I will if it's not answered. Nice question by the way !

Comment: Hi blackSmith: Thanks for the response. That was very helpful.